# Typescript Generic chained function to Swift

Tags: swift, typescript, generics

I'm really struggling to comprehend how to (if even possible) to convert a generics function written in Typescript into something I can use in Swift.

```
export type Filter<T> = (value: T) => boolean

export function isKeyEqualToValue<T>(key: keyof T) {
  return function (value: T[keyof T]): Filter<T> {
    return (object: T) => object[key] === value
  }
}
```

```
isKeyEqualToValue<T>('key')(someObject.key)
```

```
const filters = userFilters.map(userFilterSet => isEvery(buildAlertFilter(userFilterSet)))
  const isMatch = isAny(filters)

  return flow.reduce((feed: String[], obj: SomeType) => {
    if (!isMatch(obj)) return feed

    return [
      ...feed,
      {
         ...obj 
      },
    ]
  }, [])
}
```

I would like to be able to input a struct model in for T and check if the inputted value matches the key. Would greatly appreciate some guidance here!

EDIT:

I've added how the method is being called and used.  Essentially I'm trying to avoid doing an algorithm O(n)^2 and so I'm trying to build a list of filters based on our user's choice.  Then cross check the bulk of my data (`SomeType`) with those built filters.

I'm working to translate another function using the similar principles.

```
export function hasInArray<T>(key: keyof T) {
  return function (values: Array<any>): Filter<T> {
    return (object: T) => values.includes((object[key] as unknown) as string)
  }
}
```

This is what I have so far.

```
func notInArray<Root, Value>(for keyPath: KeyPath<Root, Value>) -> (Array<Any>) -> Filter<Root, Value> {
    { values in { object in !values.contains(where: object[keyPath: keyPath]) } } }
```

Comment: It depends on how you intend to call this in Swift. What interface are you expecting? TypeScrip's `keyof T` is very similar to, but subtly different, than Swift's `KeyPath`. Whether those subtleties matter depend entirely on how you intend to use this in Swift. Most importantly, TypeScript allows the use of strings as if they were property names. Swift does not. Typically when using `keyof` this doesn't matter, but some clever uses can force it to matter.

Comment: @RobNapier I've added some more infromation. Apologies this is the first time I'm posting on stack overflow, still learning.

Comment: I believe my answer below does exactly what you're describing. Are you having some difficulty?

Comment: I've added another function I'm working on and struggling to convert over. Your other answer is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given how you expect to use this, so I need to make some assumptions. I'm assuming the TypeScript that calls this looks like this:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const key: keyof Person = "name";
const nameTester = isKeyEqualToValue(key);
const person = {name: "Alice", age: 23};
const result = nameTester("Alice")(person);
```

The equivalent to TypeScript's `keyof` in Swift is `KeyPath`. Keeping this as close to the TypeScript syntax as possible to make it easier to see how it maps, this would look like:

```swift
typealias Filter<T> = (_ value: T) -> Bool

func isKeyEqualToValue<T, Value>(key: KeyPath<T, Value>) -> (Value) -> (T) -> Bool
where Value: Equatable
{
    return { (value: Value) -> Filter<T> in
        return { (object: T) in object[keyPath: key] == value }
    }
}

struct Person: Equatable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

let key = \Person.name
let nameTester = isKeyEqualToValue(key: key)
let person = Person(name: "Alice", age: 23)
let result = nameTester("Alice")(person)
```

To make it better Swift (rather than matching the TypeScript so closely), it would look like:

```swift
typealias Filter<Root, Value: Equatable> = (Value) -> (Root) -> Bool

func isEqualToValue<Root, Value>(for keyPath: KeyPath<Root, Value>) -> Filter<Root, Value>
{
    { value in { object in object[keyPath: keyPath] == value } }
}

let nameTester = isEqualToValue(for: key)
```

---

Your second example is like the first.

```
func hasInArray<Root, Values>(for keyPath: KeyPath<Root, Values>) -> (Values.Element) -> (Root) -> Bool
where Values: Sequence, Values.Element: Equatable
{
    { value in { object in object[keyPath: keyPath].contains(value) } }
}
```

You will almost never want `Array<Any>`. You need an array of the specific element. But in this case you don't need an array at all; you just need any Sequence.

---

All this said, I wouldn't do it this way. I think it's much easier to understand if you create a Filter type to manage it.

```
// A Filter object over a specific Target object (for example, a Person)
struct Filter<Target> {
    let passes: (Target) -> Bool
}

// Filters can be created many ways
extension Filter {
    // By properties equal to a value
    static func keyPath<Value>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Target, Value>, equals value: Value) -> Filter
    where Value: Equatable
    {
        Filter { target in
            target[keyPath: keyPath] == value
        }
    }

    // By properties containing a value
    static func keyPath<Seq>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Target, Seq>, contains value: Seq.Element) -> Filter
    where Seq: Sequence, Seq.Element: Equatable
    {
        Filter { target in
            target[keyPath: keyPath].contains(value)
        }
    }

    // By a property being a member of a sequence
    static func keyPath<Seq>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Target, Seq.Element>, isElementOf seq: Seq) -> Filter
    where Seq: Sequence, Seq.Element: Equatable
    {
        Filter { target in
            seq.contains(target[keyPath: keyPath])
        }
    }

    // By combining other filters
    static func all(of filters: [Filter]) -> Filter {
        Filter { target in
            filters.allSatisfy { filter in filter.passes(target) }
        }
    }
}

struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var children: [String]
}

let filter: Filter<Person> = .all(of: [
    .keyPath(\.name, equals: "Alice"),
    .keyPath(\.children, contains: "Bob"),
    .keyPath(\.age, isElementOf: [23, 43]),
])

let alice = Person(name: "Alice", age: 23, children: ["Bob"])
let shouldInclude = filter.passes(alice)  // true
```

Comment: this is amazing! thank you so much for your help here!

Comment: Hold on I just spent some more time with the second solution.  I need the reverse of that.  The values are not a sequence the value is a single value that I'm checking in a sequence for existence

Comment: Okay let me dig into this, but at face value this method makes more sense. Really appreciate the guidance!!

Comment: Added a `keyPath(_:isElementOf:)` that matches the example you're describing.